# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float' while importing nibabel

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, medical-imaging, nibabel

When i try to install nibabel lirary i get an error like this. Tried different version of numpy and didn't work out. Any idea how to solve this?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-954ce44cd9c4> in <module>
----> 1 import nibabel as nb
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import sys

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    303 
    304         if attr in __former_attrs__:
--> 305             raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    306 
    307         # Importing Tester requires importing all of UnitTest which is not a

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

To get an solution for an error i am facing.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of `nibabel` (5.0.1 Fed 2033 according to the github repository)?  They should have corrected this deprecation issue by now.  If it still is a problem, raise an issue at its repository.  Downgrading your numpy (from 1.24) should remove the error, but not the warning.

Comment: I changed the np.float to float in source file and it worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: error appeared in  this line 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/nibabel/quaternions.py in <module>
     29 import numpy as np
     30 
---> 31 MAX_FLOAT = np.maximum_sctype(np.float)
     32 FLOAT_EPS = np.finfo(np.float).eps
     33 

so i went to /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/nibabel/quaternions.py and changed the np.float to float in source file then it worked.

Comment: Also problem appears to be happaning when we use TPU as our backend engine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version incompatibility in your environment. This bug was fixed in https://github.com/nipy/nibabel/pull/964, which was included in the [3.2.1 release](https://github.com/nipy/nibabel/releases/tag/3.2.1).

To resolve this, you either need to upgrade nibabel or downgrade numpy.